# DIV with overflow size - take maximum available space

Tags: css, html

I have a document like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.result {
height: 500px;
overflow: auto;
width: 900px;
}
</style>
<div class="options"></div>
<div class="result">
<table>
<!--here I have large table-->
</table>
</div>
```

This gives me a fixed size box with scrollbars.
I would like my result box to take rest of available size in browser and still have scrollbars(if there are necessary)

So that my options div will stay on top and below will be another div having width of 100% and height of remaining browser height.

Is it possible?

This is the result I would like to get:
[image] 
So when I resize browser scrollbars will be on right and on bottom, something like iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set absolute sizes and positions to your options and result elements:

```
div.options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; // Set height of the options box
    padding: 0;
}

div.result {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px; // Same as options box
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: scroll; // Could be auto too
}
```

This should work fine.

Comment: this works just fine :) but is it possible to add fixed header to my table? I'm using asp GridView inside updatepanel so I prefer simple css solution. I was trying to do it by copying table header and placing it above my table, then adding position:fixed, but that's not working correct.

Comment: You mean that black/gradient title bar above the table in your image?

Comment: yes, this is just styled header. Now it is part of table, but I would like it to stay on top, so when I scroll table vertical it will stay on top and when I scroll horizontal it will move.

Comment: I was trying to use http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html but my table can't have fixed width for columns :/

Comment: You should try playing around with absolute or fixed positions or maybe search the web for some javascript/jquery solutions, but I can't really tell you how to do that myself. :(

Comment: I found couple of jQuery solutions, I must check them out, thanks anyway for help with my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible!

Try position:absolute that fills up to all sides

```
  div.result {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

or the border-box solution that keeps the width independent of margins and paddings (so we can use margins while width:100% still applies correctly)

```
  div.result {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-top: 100px; /* Or whatever you need */
  }
```